# one-click-save all open tabs as web page files to disk in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any way in Google Chrome to save all or selected open tabs in all windows to disk? I don't mean to save the state of windows and tabs I have open, or bookmark them, but rather to automatically save all pages to disk as webpage files.

Pre-quantum-firefox **HAD** this ability by means of this [extension](http://maf.mozdev.org/maff-file-format.html/).

Pale-moon has this ability by means of this [extension](https://addons.palemoon.org/addon/mozarchiver/).

Is there an identical or similar functionality by means of any extension for **google chrome**?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [SingleFile](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/singlefile/mpiodijhokgodhhofbcjdecpffjipkle/related?hl=en). It saves pages in html format and additionally:

> - You can also process multiple tabs in one click and save:
>
>   - the selected tabs,
>   - the unpinned tabs,
>   - all the tabs.
> - The context menu also allows you to activate the auto-save (after pages are being loaded) of:
>
>   - the current tab,
>   - the unpinned tabs,
>   - all the tabs.